# Array subscript is not an integer when loading plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, plist, nsdictionary

I'm very new to iOS / Objective C, but I've been programming for a number of years in a number of different languages.

Our company has taken on an existing iOS application for modifications. Right now I'm trying to load a plist file and populate a UITableView with it's contents. I'm getting errors with my code to create the cell and I'm not sure what's going on.

Here is my plist file, very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>title</key><string>Un</string>
            <key>subtitle</key><string>Subtitle</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>title</key><string>Deux</string>
            <key>subtitle</key><string>Subtitle</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

Here is where I load the plist file into memory:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"resources" ofType:@"plist"];
    resources = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath];
}
```

And here is where I try to access the properties. I've added comments where I'm getting errors at compile time:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int index = (int) indexPath.row;
    UITableViewCell *cell =[factory cellOfKind:@"cell" forTable:tableView];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    UILabel *lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *lblSubtitle = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    NSDictionary *resource = resources[index]; // incompatible types in initialization
    NSString *row_title = resource[@"title"]; // array subscript is not an integer
    NSString *row_subtitle = resource[@"subtitle"]; // array subscript is not an integer
    [lblTitle setText: row_title];
    [lblSubtitle setText: row_subtitle];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of `clang`? GCC and old Clangs don't recognize this construct.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm almost positive I'm not. Because of both the older source code of the existing project and only having access to a mac with 10.6.8, I'm running XCode 3.2.6 and compiling for iOS 4.2. I've been resisting upgrading any or all of this unless it was necessary. Would you recommend "another construct" (if that's possible) or an I going to need to upgrade for some other reason down the line?

Comment: there's another construct, see my answer.

Comment: @raydowe In short, this is "Modern Objective-C" introduced in Xcode 4.4 and 4.5. See the WWDC 2012 [session 405](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405) and [session 413](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=413). Also, a minor detail, but your subject line refers to non-numeric array subscripts. It's actually the `NSDictionary` objects that have non-numeric subscripts. The `NSArray` objects have numeric subscripts (which is, itself, a new feature).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As H2CO3 said, this syntax is part of the object subscripting that's part of "Modern Objective-C", which was released in conjunction with Xcode 4.4 and 4.5.

For a discussion of your non-numeric subscripts, visit the [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) site and scroll down to the section titled "Subscripting Methods" (what Apple sometimes calls the "boxing syntax" or the "boxed syntax"), you'll see it discussed there. I've included other references at the bottom of my answer.

The first example, is **array-style subscripting**, for looking up values in an array:

```
NSArray *resources = ... // however it was defined
NSDictionary *resource = resources[index];
```

The compiler translates this to:

```
NSDictionary *resource = [resources objectAtIndexedSubscript:index];
```

If you don't want to upgrade Xcode (and the compiler) on your machine, you can replace that you can simply replace the array-style subscripting with the traditional `objectAtIndex` syntax:

```
NSDictionary *resource = [resources objectAtIndex:index];
```

Likewise, the second example you showed us was with the non-numeric subscript. This is **dictionary-style subscripting**:

```
NSString *row_title = resource[@"title"];
```

Which the compiler will translate to:

```
NSString *row_title = [resource objectForKeyedSubscript:@"title"];
```

And, again, if you don't want to upgrade your Xcode (and its compiler), the traditional equivalent is:

```
NSString *row_title = [resource objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Bottom line, maybe you'll be lucky, this use of the subscripting of the `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` is limited to this method. But the project have been refactored to use "Modern Objective-C", and you might see other Modern Objective-C constructs, such as **array literals**:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];
```

If you have that anywhere in this project, your old compiler will not understand that array literal syntax, and you'll have to replace it with:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
```

Likewise, you might see **dictionary literals**:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key1" : @"value1", @"key2" : @"value2"};
```

You'll have to replace that with:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
```

Finally, you may have **numeric literals** too, e.g.:

```
NSNumber *number = @4;
NSNumber *done = @YES;
```

That's equivalent to

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];
NSNumber *done = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

Depending upon how much Modern Objective-C your project has, there may be quite a few edits that you may have to perform. Alternatively, if you could upgrade to Xcode 4.5 or later, and you'll be able to compile this code without incident.

There are quite a few other very useful constructs in Xcode 4.5, including the new `NSDictionary` enumerating methods, the typed enums, string literals, etc. You should watch the WWDC 2012 sessions on Modern Objective-C, so that you will know what you're missing out on by sticking with your old compiler, and also so you can figure out how to decipher Modern Objective-C code you may see posted here on Stack Overflow or elsewhere.

For more information see:

- "Literal syntax" section of the [discussion of arrays in the Programming with Objective C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW13)
- [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) discussion at the LLVM site
- WWDC 2012 [Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405)
- WWDC 2012 [Migrating to Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=413)
- See the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html) to better understand what features were added with which versions of Xcode

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation. The links at the bottom have already proven very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because apparently you're using an older compiler that doesn't recognize the new object literal syntax. If you don't wish to upgrade, use the appropriate instance methods on `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *resource = [resources objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *row_title = [resource objectForKey:@"title"];
NSString *row_subtitle = [resource objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
```

If you choose this approach, you'll maintain backwards compatibility, which is good.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why I've been having problems with the syntax in much of the example code I've found.